# WPF MouseWheel and KeyDown not called without input focus?

Tags: wpf, focus, keydown, mousewheel

I have a custom class (ItemsContainer) which contains a few buttons & UserControls.

I'm implementing a navigation system using mouse & inputs, and the user can 'pan' using right-click... but unless the user clicks something interactive (button, etc), my methods for 'mousewheel' and 'keydown' aren't called.

The best article I found so far said I needed to 'hook' myself in every control !!  It sounds silly to parse every single visual node and add EventHandlers everywhere... there must be an easier way.

Is there?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of items embedded in this question that need addressed.

First is that a `RoutedEvent` will propagate outwards and up the visual tree. Therefore if you have embedded controls within controls such as this...

```
    <Grid Name="MyGrid">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>Button 1</Button>
            <Button>Button 2</Button>
            <Button>
                <TextBlock>Button 3</TextBlock>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

...attaching an event to handle `KeyDown` behavior on `MyGrid`; will receive any `KeyDown` `RoutedEvent` from within its children.

There is one caveat in that if the event is marked handled by a control within the visual tree, which would be the case for the `Button` control and the `MouseLeftButtonDown` RoutedEvent; you would then need to adjust how you register. This is simple enough and can be done like this; where `true` is stating you want to be notifed even if another handler marked the event handled.

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyGrid.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
    }

    private void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MouseLeftButtonDown Fired");
    }
```

If you were to step through with the debugger you will see that the source of the RoutedEvent when you click on the text *Button 3* is indeed the `TextBlock`.

This will address your need to hook into varying controls; since you can leverage the varying `RoutedEvents`.

Focus still must exist somewhere within the application however; that can be easily set via the parent control and calling `Focus`.